# sampling bug in R?

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to sample one element out of a numeric vector.

When the length of the vector > 1, the result is one of the numbers of the vector, as expected. However when the vector contains one element, it samples a number between 0 and this single number.

For example:

```
sample(c(100, 1000), 1)
```

results in either 100 or 1000, however

```
sample(c(100), 1)
```

results in different numbers smaller than 100.

What is going on?

Comment: Writing `c(100)` is like writing `100`. Then, you will get your answer by typing `?sample`.

Comment: It's a convenience built in `sample`. you can create your own `sample_n` function and check length before sampling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Details](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/sample) of the sample function:

"If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x"

Answer (score 2):

This is (unfortunately) expected behavior. See `?sample`. The first line of the *Details* section:

> If `x` has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and `x >= 1`, sampling via sample takes place from `1:x`. Note that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour when `x` is of varying length in calls such as `sample(x)`. See the examples.

Luckily the `Examples` section provides a suggested fix:

```
# sample()'s surprise -- example
x <- 1:10
    sample(x[x >  8]) # length 2
    sample(x[x >  9]) # oops -- length 10!
    sample(x[x > 10]) # length 0

## safer version:
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
resample(x[x >  8]) # length 2
resample(x[x >  9]) # length 1
resample(x[x > 10]) # length 0
```

You could, of course, also just use an `if` statement:

```
sampled_x = if (length(my_x) == 1) my_x else sample(my_x, size = 1)
```